# Removing Lists of Tables, etc. entries from glossaries

Tags: glossaries

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\printglossaries
\newglossaryentry{example}{
    name={example},
    description={example}
}
\clearpage
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4   
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\gls{example}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, in the list of glossaries created, example is shown to exist in both pages: its actual use, and its caption use as extracted in the list of tables.
I know I can edit the caption for list of tables, etc., but I was wondering if there is any option to automatically remove those entries entirely.

Comment: I don't know a way to automate this, but using `\caption[\glsentryname{example}]{\gls{example}}` is not so difficult...

Comment: I know it isn't, and I mentioned that I am aware of that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option to automatically remove those entries, which is why the `glossaries` manual cautions against using those commands in captions and section headings. However you could temporarily redefine `\gls` in the front matter and reset it at the start of the document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\let\ORGgls\gls
\renewcommand*{\gls}[2][]{\glsentrytext{#2}}
\listoftables
\let\gls\ORGgls

\printglossaries
\newglossaryentry{example}{
    name={example},
    description={example}
}
\clearpage
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\gls{example}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```